# How to redirect to dynamic subdomain on authentication in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement multi tenancy where each registered user will have their own subdomain -e.g. user_subdomain.example.com

My users authenticate on example.com - how can I redirect them to their subdomain on successful login/registration? -For example to user1.example.com

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation, Laravel has a handy way of doing this:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Comment: fyi, answers should contain code to solve a problem. If the posted URL is down/unreachable this answer will be of no use to anyone.

Comment: Yeah, I have domain group routing setup, works fine when I go to subdomains. My issue is setting up a logic of redirecting users to their subdomains after successful authentication.

Comment: Then I think I don't understand the question. Do you mean the actual process of redirecting? Or do you mean you want to override the standard route after a login procedure?

Answer (score 0):

check this example https://medium.com/@pagcosma/multi-subdomain-sessions-in-laravel-40fd31b199fa

I have doing tests with succes ;)

Comment: fyi, answers should contain code to solve a problem. If the posted URL is down/unreachable this answer will be of no use to anyone.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting but not quite what I'm looking for.